# Is there a way to prevent a callback from firing in dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have the following callbacks:

```
@app.callback(
    [Output("useridPicker", "value"), Output("datePicker", "date"), ],
    [Input("url", "search")]
)
def update_form_default(url_search):
    return 111, dt.today()


@app.callback(
    Output("url", "search"),
    [Input("useridPicker", "value"), Input("datePicker", "date")]
)
def update_current_url(userid, date):
    return f"?userid=111&date=2020-06-29"
```

I have one text-area to pick a userid (`useridPicker`), a date picker to pick a date (`datePicker`) and a url containing as params the current userid and the current date ("YYYY-MM-DD").

When I modify the date or the userid from the url, I would like to update the displayed values inside (`useridPicker`) and (`datePicker`). And vice-versa.

For now, I get the following error:

> Error: Dependency Cycle Found: useridPicker.value -> url.search ->
> useridPicker.value

When inside a callback, is there a way to prevent another callback from firing? In order to avoid this circular dependencies error and a possible infinite loop between callbacks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to abort a Dash callback in two ways. You can either raise a `dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate` exception to abort the whole callback, or you can return `dash.no_update` for each of the outputs that you do not wish to update.

Comment: is it possible to suppress this exception?

Answer (score 2):

@emher is correct about the options for aborting a callback early, but that won't resolve the issue with having circular callbacks (a restriction in `React.js` underneith `dash`).

The `dash` documentation about advanced callbacks has some suggestions how to avoid circular callbacks: https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks.

> As of dash v1.19.0, you can create circular updates within the same
> callback.
>
> Circular callback chains that involve multiple callbacks are not
> supported.
>
> Circular callbacks can be used to keep multiple inputs synchronized to
> each other.

The trick is to replace your two callbacks with a single callback with multiple outputs, and to use `dash.callback_context.triggered` within the callback to detect which of the inputs were modified to fire the callback. You can use `no_update` to only update the outputs that need to be changed. Something like this:

```py
from dash import callback_context, no_update

@app.callback(
    Output("url", "search"),
    Output("useridPicker", "value"),
    Output("datePicker", "date"),
    Input("url", "search"),
    Input("useridPicker", "value"),
    Input("datePicker", "date"),
)
def update_form_default(url_search):
    changed_inputs = [
        x["prop_id"]
        for x in callback_context.triggered
    ]
    if "url.search" in changed_inputs:
        return no_update, 111, dt.today()
    else:
        return f"?userid=111&date=2020-06-29", no_update, no_update
```