# How to prevent callback controls on Plotly Dash which set their values to default?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, updates, dashboard

I am using plotly to create the dashboard. I have some controls and some indicators. I used  dash_bootstrap_components in the dash design. The problem is when the callback is fired to update indicators, the controls are updated also and the presented values of controls configured back to the default values. This leads to confusion, since the configuration on dash does not match the presented result on dash.

**Tried: **

- I removed the dcc.Interval config for controls
- Disabled all controls and indicators and just keep one control and one indicator. Every time the callback is fired to update the indicator, the control is updated also to the default value.
  Find some solution if you would like to prevent the indicator update as it is here: [Is there a way to prevent a callback from firing in dash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62642418/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-a-callback-from-firing-in-dash)
  But this is not what we want. I did not find on stackoverflow the right answer for my case.

**Expectation:** Only the indicators on dash are updated but not the whole dashboard including controls to default values.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the issue is the following. Assume I have a tool that creates images and saves them in a given directory. Every image has a unique name (including time stamp). To show them on GUI, I started to do:

- Copy first image (nr. i) from another directory to assets folder and then show the image on GUI.
- Then, in second iteration, I am copying next image number, for example i+1, to assets folder as in step1 and then show the image on GUI. After that to keep the assets folder clean, image i is deleted. The process is repeated.

The issue has been fixed by giving the direct path to src image instead of using assets_path and copy process. More information can be found here: https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-embed-images-into-a-dash-app/61839